# Git - игнорирование всей директории, кроме определенного файла в ней

Tags: git, gitignore

В моем проекте есть директория, например, **folder_name**. В ней есть поддиректории folder1, folder2, folder3. Директория folder1 содержит файл *example.json*. Дело в том, что мне нужно, чтобы директория **folder_name** была в .gitignore, но файл *example.json* оттуда исключить. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно написать такое правило в .gitignore?

Comment: а если добавить всю папку в гитигнор, а 1 файл руками добавить через add?

Comment: `git add -f folder1/example.json`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Примерно такой *.gitignore* файл должен получиться в **folder_name**

```
/folder1/*
/folder2/*
/folder3/*
!/folder1/example.json
```

Оператор **!** исключает одно значение.